# ajax callServer ajp still empty

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a website for a project so it will be locally and I am in the point where I want to use Ajax for a login form I made. I dont know very much about ajax but this is a code I found it doesnt work but I dont know what else I should do, and what exactly am I expecting. An ajp file with what inside? Thanks in advance
This is the javascript code:

```
function callServer(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var xmlString = 
                        "<profile>" + 
                        "<username>" + escape(username) +"</username>" + 
                        "<password>" + escape(password) +"</password>" +                            
                        "</profile>";
// Build the URL to connect to
var url = "file:///C:/Users/admin/Documents/project/savelogin.jsp";
// Open a connection to the server
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
// Tell the server you're sending it XML 
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
 // Set up a function for the server to run when it's done
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = confirmUpdate;
// Send the request
xmlHttp.send(xmlString);
 }
```

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="login.js"></script>
<title>Project-Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="loginform">
    <div>
    <p id="insertinfo">Type your info to log in your account:</p>
    <label for="Username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Type your username"/>
    </div>
     <div>
    <label for="password">Type password:</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Type your password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="loginButton">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="loginbutton" onclick="callServer()" />
    </div>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What will you be doing with the values that you retrieve from HTML?

Her is an example from w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp

But what you want is:

```
  <script>
 function retrieveValues() {

var value1 = document.getElementById("username").value;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =   xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "thePhpPage.php?q=" + value1, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

But here the variables are passed onto a php function. If you want something similar on your local machine you need to install lamp or wamp depending on your OS.